# How to install resolvconf on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, dns

I noticed that resolvconf is not working correctly, the DNS settings never changed when interfaces or dns servers change, i can't find any trace of resolvconf and can't reinstall it back. anyone knows the package name or something i can do to resolve this.

Comment: I think it's `openresolv` but are you sure you need it? Are you unhappy with network-manager?

Comment: I don't use network manager. i managed to install `openresolv` don't know why apt-get was not finding it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Raspbian by default resolvconf is managed by *openresolv*:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt list openresolv
Listing... Done
openresolv/stable,now 3.8.0-1 armhf [installed,automatic]
```

It is configured in `/etc/resolvconf.conf` and you can just reinstall it from the repository with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install --reinstall openresolv
```

There is an alternative with *systemd-resolvd* but I don't know if it works out of the box, means without *systemd-networkd*. You can try it with:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo sed -i '1i resolvconf=NO' /etc/resolvconf.conf
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

The first command will disable `openresolv` without deinstalling it. So you can easily revert by deleting the inserted first line in `/etc/resolvconf.conf`, disable the service and delete the symbolic link.

Comment: ended up installing this, for some weird reason `apt-get install resolvconf` just didn't work. (tried again later just to check why that package is not found and i was able to install it ... go figure)